# Files encrypted with af21 file extension

Tags: windows-7, file-recovery, file-extension, ransomware

I have a set of files which got encrypted during the recent ransomware attack. All of the files have a common extension `.af21` . I am able to play the video files using VLC, although they have the same extension.

I have a windows 7 ultimate system.

How can I recover these files?

Comment: What do you mean by “I am able to play the video files using VLC”? How is this related to the supposedly encrypted files?

Comment: One of the folders contain only video files only. Although the file names are encrypted, I'm able to play the video in vlc.

Comment: So just rename the files back? You could use the [file command](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) to determine the file type.

Comment: I already tried that. It didn't work. The filenames are encrypted as well.